# Asking direct question about attitude in online survey

Tags: research-process

I want to ask my participants directly about their attitude. What is the best way to do it?
Is it enough if I only ask:

I have a positive attitude (rating with 5-point Likert scale from totally agree to totally disagree). Because if they click on totally disagree, I can translate that to having a negative attitude and if they click in the middle of the scale it can be translated as a neutral attitude?

Or should I let them rate all three options:

I have a positive attitude (from totally agree to totally disagree)

I have a neutral attitude (from totally agree to totally disagree)

I have a negative attitude (from totally agree to totally disagree)

(It has to be with a 5-point Likert scale)

Thank you!

Comment: You just need to make sure you design the questions properly, this should give you an idea : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0ZZJXw4MTA

Answer (score 1):

While you will get numbers with such a question they won't mean anything. This is the sort of question that people will naturally skew toward "positive attitude" regardless of their actual attitude. The second method will also get you potentially inconsistent results.

Instead, you need a set of questions that will be honestly answered, maybe responding to scenarios, and from which you can infer the attitude.

Asking "Are you smart?" gets just noise. Some people answer the opposite of what they truly are for a variety of psychological reasons.

Comment: I know... I also have questions like that. I still have to put the direct question about attitude in it though, so I'm just wondering what's the best way to do it...

Comment: I don't understand why you _need_ to ask a question that is pretty much guaranteed to yield meaningless results. Such a question wastes people's time and if they recognize that then they might also decide to sabotage the rest of the survey.

Comment: My professor wants it that way :-/

Comment: Perhaps you have misunderstood something.